# CKEditor controls show in IE8 and FireFox but not in Safari or Opera

Tags: php, ckeditor

I have a PHP developer working on a site for me, using CKEditor 3.2, and the editing controls appear perfectly for him in IE8 (Windows) and for me in Firefox 3.5 (Mac). But my other browsers on Mac (Opera 10 and Safari 4) show no editing controls but only the word "FALSE" centered above the text area.

The textarea contains the "raw HTML" of the content, instead of it being rendered properly.

I'm not a programmer, my guy doesn't have a Mac, and he thinks IE8 and FF are enough!!

Can anyone suggest where he's likely to be going wrong in his call to CKEditor in PHP, given that word "FALSE" appearig where it does.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be very difficult to suggest a solution without seeing any code. What I can tell you is that CKEditor should at least show controls for Safari and Opera. I'm using CKEditor on a few sites and it loads for me. However, I can say that Safari support is sketchy. Safari's implementation of `contentEditable` doesn't seem as stable as it is in Firefox.

Comment: Yes, you really have to look at the code that creates the CKEditor because that developer might have added a check to enable only IE and Firefox.